# How to do a wizard in a website?

Tags: javascript, http, browser, http-post

In a website, I'd like to implement a [wizard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_%28software%29). It should look like a sequence of forms.

My requirements are:

- The user should be able to use back and forwards browser buttons without being prompted to re-submit a form (when going back and forth).
- If the user goes back or forward on a previously filled page, the fields should be auto-completed
- If the user tries to access a page without having filled the previous steps, he should be redirected accordingly (last required page).
- The user should be able to resume the form completion after leaving and coming back.
- In my model, each page required the previous one to be filled. And each page has its own validation.
- Url's should be pretty.
- The wizard should work without javascript (but not mandatory).

How would you implement it ? (series of http post forms, http get forms, submit via javascript or not ?)

---

Toughts:

I plan to store every info in the session, and at the end of the wizard, save info in database and erase the current session info. This way I am able to auto-complete the fields, and know where the user is in the completion of the wizard.

My main concerns:

- If I implement with http posts forms, the browser will prompt to resubmit each form (and I don't know how to gain control over that)
- If I implement it with http GET forms, the urls are filled with info, and can be quite long. And it's not the means of a GET request.
- If I submit each form via http post via javascript, there will be no prompt, but my wizard would not work with javascript (maybe a solution is to override the default form behavior to have it work with and without javascript)

Comment: Why not simply use jQuery tabs (styled to look like a multi step Wizard process) within a single form?

Comment: @Kane Good idea. But it would require some javascript for the validation of each step (submiting only the relevant fields), and the no-javascript fallback would be one giant form.

Comment: Can you exhibit a wizard you like on a public website?

Comment: @Colonel Panic Obviously this one is best: http://voyageronline.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/nerdrage031.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using session for arbitrary data storage! That tends to get messy fast, and also messes with the security model if you end up using session for login auth. Keep your auth separate from your settings data and create a table specifically for settings, or use javascript localStorage!

In your case, what you're describing pretty much sounds to me like one long form that has show/hide functionality with multiple form sections, with the added quirk of persistent storage!

In other words, instead of `form1 > form2 > form3 > form4 > done`

`form_section_1 > validate, save data, and then display form_section_2 and hide form_section_1 > validate, save data, and then display form_section_3 and hide form_section_2 > etc > true form submit once`

For users without javascript, just validate their info in php across all sections upon submit of any of the sections.  You can store their info identified by their session_id to a settings table if you really want to make it store even for edge cases.

For simplicity's sake in this scenario, I would use localStorage to store all the data on every validation, and use javascript to prevent accidentally leaving the main form.  If you really must complicate your life by supporting, like, ie7 ( http://caniuse.com/#search=localStorage ), then detect for localStorage and in it's absence, pass the data to a php script that would then put it into a single data-container object and converts it all to a single bundle of json to be saved in a single variable in the session, or even better, in a settings table in the database.

Answer (score -1):

I would use PHP session variables to store the filled in data between the different pages of the wizard. By using a html form you will get prompts to resend data if you go back through the browser history, I do not know a fix for this... Storing the variables is easy with PHP though, give the form `method=post` and use the `$_REQUEST` command to retrieve the info in your PHP document to avoid the long URL's from using `GET`. Good luck, will update if I think of anything.

Comment: Also, I would validate the forms using javascript but store it in PHP as said above.

Comment: I don't recommend using session for arbitrary data storage!  That tends to get messy fast, and also messes with the security model if you end up using session for login auth.  Keep your auth separate from your settings data and create a table specifically for settings, or use localStorage!